mysql biometrics log summarization per shifting schedule
I have this table from fingerprint sensor and I need to show the result in one row

select x.empno,
    x.am_in as am_in,
    x.am_out as am_out,
    x.pm_in as pm_in,
    x.pm_out as pm_out,
    x.ov_in as ov_in,
    x.ov_out as ov_out
from(select empno,
    min(case when punch_code = '0' then punch_datetime end) am_in,
    max(case when punch_code = '1' then punch_datetime end) am_out,
    min(case when punch_code = '2' then punch_datetime end) pm_in,
    max(case when punch_code = '3' then punch_datetime end) pm_out,
    min(case when punch_code = '4' then punch_datetime end) ov_in,
    max(case when punch_code = '5' then punch_datetime end) ov_out

from biometric_log
where punch_code in ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
group by empno, punch_datetime
order by empno, punch_datetime
) x
group by x.empno, x.am_in, x.am_out, x.pm_in, x.pm_out, x.ov_in, x.ov_out
order by x.empno;

the problem is my shifting schedule is from 8 am to 4 pm, 4 pm to 12 mn, 12 mn to 8 am and the regular 8 am to 5 pm schedule.
this is what it looks like with this code

what I want is that the timed in and out of every employee will align everyday that he time in and out whatever his schedule is. My database is mysql database.

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, #5 and #3

Remove punch_datetime from the GROUP BY, and see what happens.

If i remove the puch_datetime from the GROUP BY it will result to grouping the empno which will result to a single line for every empno which does not show the everyday time in and out of the employee.

Your odd GROUP BY is the reason you try another GROUP BY (to get SELECT DISTINCT result.)

Make it easy to assist you - simpify! (Perhaps 2 or 3 punch_codes are enough?) Provide a consistent [mcve]. Create a fiddle (https://dbfiddle.uk can be used).

@isabel don't share the image, share sample sql data table(sql query). Also share the expected output

Assuming that every punch-in has a punch-out row in biometric_log table, you could use Lead() Over() analytic (window) function to get your in/out data in the same row.
Here I put them together within punch-in row. The same could be done in punch-out row just using the LAG() Over() analytic function.
Didn't quite sure what is the role of am_in/out, pm_in/out so I put them as in_out_type as a kind of description of in/out datetimes.
WITH      --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
  biometric_log ( machine_code, empno, punch_code, punch_date_time ) AS
    ( Select 6, '000061', 1, '2024-02-01 08:03:00' Union ALl
      --
      Select 6, '000061', 2, '2024-02-01 23:40:00' Union ALl
      Select 6, '000061', 1, '2024-02-02 08:03:00' Union ALl
      --
      Select 6, '000061', 2, '2024-02-02 23:46:00' Union ALl
      Select 6, '000061', 1, '2024-02-03 08:05:00' Union ALl
  
      Select 6, '000061', 2, '2024-02-03 23:33:00' Union All
      Select 6, '000061', 1, '2024-02-04 08:04:00' Union ALl
      --
      Select 6, '000061', 2, '2024-02-05 15:43:00' Union All
      Select 6, '000061', 1, '2024-02-06 00:03:00' Union All
      --
      Select 6, '000061', 2, '2024-02-06 15:53:00' Union All
      Select 6, '000061', 1, '2024-02-07 00:03:00' Union All
      --
      Select 6, '000061', 2, '2024-02-07 15:43:00' Union All
      Select 6, '000061', 1, '2024-02-08 00:03:00' Union All
      --
      Select 6, '000061', 2, '2024-02-08 15:54:00' Union All
      Select 6, '000061', 1, '2024-02-09 00:02:00' Union All
      -- 
      Select 6, '000061', 2, '2024-02-09 15:51:00' Union All
      Select 6, '000061', 1, '2024-02-10 00:02:00' Union All
      --
      Select 6, '000061', 2, '2024-02-10 15:52:00' Union All
      Select 6, '000061', 1, '2024-02-11 00:03:00' Union All
      --
      Select 6, '000061', 2, '2024-02-11 15:55:00' Union All
      Select 6, '000061', 1, '2024-02-12 00:01:00' Union All
      --
      Select 6, '000061', 0, '2024-02-12 07:58:00' Union All
      Select 6, '000061', 3, '2024-02-12 16:03:00' Union All
      --
      Select 6, '000061', 0, '2024-02-13 07:56:00' Union All
      Select 6, '000061', 3, '2024-02-13 16:03:00' 
    ),

... create a cte to define punch_code types and directions to be used as joined data in the main SQL ...
  punch_codes ( punch_code, type, dir ) AS 
    ( Select 0, 'am_in', 'in'  Union All 
      Select 1, 'am_out', 'out' Union All 
      --
      Select 2, 'pm_in', 'in'  Union All 
      Select 3, 'pm_out', 'out' Union All
      --
      Select 4, 'ov_in', 'in'  Union All 
      Select 5, 'ov_out', 'out' 
    ) 

--      M a i n    S Q L : 
SELECT   a.empno, a.in_date_time, a.out_date_time, a.in_out_type
FROM   ( Select      bl.machine_code, bl.empno, bl.punch_code, bl.punch_date_time,
                     Case When pc.dir = 'in' 
                          Then bl.punch_date_time
                     End as in_date_time, 
                     Case When pc.dir = 'in' 
                          Then Lead(bl.punch_date_time) 
                                    Over(Partition By bl.machine_code, bl.empno
                                         Order By Cast(bl.punch_date_time as DATETIME)) 
                     End as out_date_time,
                     Case When pc.dir = 'in' 
                          Then Concat(pc.type, 
                                      ' / ',
                                      Lead(pc.type) 
                                           Over(Partition By bl.machine_code, bl.empno
                                           Order By Cast(bl.punch_date_time as DATETIME)) 
                                     )
                     End as in_out_type
         From        biometric_log bl
         Inner Join  punch_codes pc ON( pc.punch_code = bl.punch_code)
       ) a
WHERE    a.in_out_type Is Not Null
ORDER BY a.empno, a.punch_date_time

/*    R e s u l t : 
empno   in_date_time         out_date_time        in_out_type
------  -------------------  -------------------  --------------
000061  2024-02-01 23:40:00  2024-02-02 08:03:00  pm_in / am_out
000061  2024-02-02 23:46:00  2024-02-03 08:05:00  pm_in / am_out
000061  2024-02-03 23:33:00  2024-02-04 08:04:00  pm_in / am_out
000061  2024-02-05 15:43:00  2024-02-06 00:03:00  pm_in / am_out
000061  2024-02-06 15:53:00  2024-02-07 00:03:00  pm_in / am_out
000061  2024-02-07 15:43:00  2024-02-08 00:03:00  pm_in / am_out
000061  2024-02-08 15:54:00  2024-02-09 00:02:00  pm_in / am_out
000061  2024-02-09 15:51:00  2024-02-10 00:02:00  pm_in / am_out
000061  2024-02-10 15:52:00  2024-02-11 00:03:00  pm_in / am_out
000061  2024-02-11 15:55:00  2024-02-12 00:01:00  pm_in / am_out
000061  2024-02-12 07:58:00  2024-02-12 16:03:00  am_in / pm_out
000061  2024-02-13 07:56:00  2024-02-13 16:03:00  am_in / pm_out    */

See the fiddle here.
